# Reference chosen time range (from, to) in Grafana's Promql query

Tags: grafana, promql

I have a PromQL query max_over_time(some_metric_max[1h]) but instead of "1h" I would like to use the selected time range in Grafana. I can't find any variable for that (looking for something like $__interval, but for the selected range)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
max_over_time(some_metric_max[$__range])
```

See more details at Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable).